# How to implement a query with arguments for a custom type field

Tags: java, kotlin, spring-graphql

I want to implement pagination into custom type fields using arguments.

Using a sample schema like this:

```
type Book {
    title: String!
    year: Int!
}

type Author {
    name: String!
    books(page: Int, size: Int, sort: String): [Book!]!
}

type Query {
    allAuthors: [Author!]!
}
```

How do I implement the query for `books(page: Int, size: Int, sort: String): [Book!]!` with Spring GraphQL? I know that the queries for the type `Query` are implemented in a `@Controller` annotated class with `@SchemaMapping` annotated methods, but that does not seem to work for my data transfer `AuthorDto` class.

The application does not throw an exception or a warning when starting up or during runtime, but using the query just gives me a generic error telling me it is not implemented.

```json
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "The field at path '/allAuthors[0]/books' was declared as a non null type, but the code involved in retrieving data has wrongly returned a null value.  The graphql specification requires that the parent field be set to null, or if that is non nullable that it bubble up null to its parent and so on. The non-nullable type is '[Book!]' within parent type 'Author'",
      "path": [
        "allAuthors",
        0,
        "books"
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "classification": "NullValueInNonNullableField"
      }
    }
  ],
  "data": null
}
```

I've tried using the `@SchemaMapping` in the data transfer object like this:

```
data class AuthorDto(
   private val author: Author // author is the actual Author model class
) {

   val name: Int
       get(): author.name

    @SchemaMapping(typeName = "Author", field = "books")
    fun getBooks(
        @Argument page: Int? = null,
        @Argument size: Int? = null,
        @Argument sort: String? = null,
    ): List<Book> {
        // my implementation for creating the list with pagination
    }
}
```

However, Spring does not seem to pick up the implementation. Because this class uses my data model `Author` class in the constructor (like in the sample https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-graphql/blob/1.0.x/samples/webmvc-http/src/main/java/io/spring/sample/graphql/project/Project.java), I cannot annotate it with `@Controller` and doing that also wouldn't make any sense to me in the first place.

I'm using Kotlin, but I would appreciate solutions on how to accomplish that in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To implement the query `allAuthors` with Spring for GraphQL you should have the following method in your `@Controller` -annotated class:

```
@Controller
public class MyGraphqlController {
    @QueryMapping
    List<AuthorDto> allAuthors(){
        // implementation for creating the list with pagination
    }
}
```

Mind a couple of things:

1. The `AuthorDto` class (data class, Java record, etc) should have the same fields as the ones defined in your `schema.graphqls`, which seems to not be the case at the moment.
2. In your `schema.graphqls` definition, I see the `Author` has an array of `Book`, which is OK, but this field has arguments

   ```
   books(page: Int, size: Int, sort: String): [Book!]!
   ```

I'm not sure this is allowed inside a custom type definition in GraphQL (`type Book{...}`), which is not a query, mutation or subscription.

---

EDIT

Regarding the `books` inside the `Author`, I have never used `@Argument` inside a `@SchemaMapping` other than a `Query` or a `Mutation`. I would try this under your `@QueryMapping`:

```
@SchemaMapping
List<Book> books(Author author, @Argument Integer page, @Argument Integer size, @Argument String sort){     
    // your logic
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've made it to implemented the `allAuthors` query but I am still stuck on the `books` query for the `Author` type. AFAIK it is allowed to uses parameters or arguments in custom types (https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#arguments) but I haven't figured out how to implement this function with Spring GraphQL.

Comment: The idea in the edit seems to work. It was not obvious to me to add the dto to the controller function parameter list without an `@Argument` annotation. Thank you